# Joining on Address or Phone Number

Tags: sql, excel, join, left-join

I have two spreadsheets that I loaded into SQL tables. Let's call them excel1 and excel2.  I need to populate columns in excel1 from data in excel2.  The problem is, there is no keys, so I have to join on address and phone number.  I know this is not a good idea, but it's the only way. There will be errors, but  we plan to go through and manually fix later.  Anyways, the goal is to match the spreadsheets, via addresses or phone, so that NPI in excel1 links to PRVDR_NUM in excel2.

```
Select CLP_Billing_NPI As Billing_NPI
,c.FAC_NAME
,c.st_adr
,e.addr1
,e.phyaddr1
,c.phne_num
,e.phone
,PRVDR_NUM
,CRTFCT_TYPE_CD
,Case When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '1' Then  'Waived' 
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '2' Then  'PPMP'
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '3' Then  'High Cert'
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '4' Then  'PPM'
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '9' Then  'Reg'
End As LLA_CLIA_Certification_Level
,CRTFCT_EFCTV_DT
,TRMNTN_EXPRTN_DT
From [CLIA_LabFindings_NC] lf  

INNER JOIN [provider] P (NOLOCK)
on lf.CLP_Billing_NPI = p.npi  

INNER JOIN [entity] e (NOLOCK)  
on e.entid = p.entityid  

LEFT JOIN [CLIA_POS] c (NOLOCK)  
on (c.[ST_ADR] = e.addr1
or c.[ST_ADR]  = e.[phyaddr1]
or c.[PHNE_NUM]  = e.[Phone])  

order by CLP_Billing_NPI
```

There are 2018 (only 81 unique NPIs) rows in the excel spreadsheet I need to populate with the following columns that exist excel2.  These columns are: CLIA_NUM, CRTFCT_TYPE_CD, LLA_CLIA_Certification_Level, CRTFCT_EFCTV_DT, TRMNTN_EXPRTN_DT

When I run my query, my data is crap because of the joins.  Can anyone please suggest a better way to do this?   I am trying to keep the NPI's from the spreadsheet I need to populate in order in SQL results, all 2018, so I can copy and paste from SQL to excel.

Comment: Your data is messy, your join is crap (as you know), so your result set is going to be crap. You could consider implementing a [Levenshtein distance function](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/) to do string comparison in your join and then allow through matches with a low enough Levenshtein Distance and audit from there.

Comment: By the end of the day?!?!  And you are in training for 8 hours? Your boss has given you a Kobayashi Maru test. Matching addresses with accuracy is notoriously complicated. Most companies who want to do so usually purchase software that allows you to adjust the degree of match. Your best bet is to use the link JNevill gave you for the Levenshtein distance. But possibly your boss is just looking to see how you handle pressure for a task that can't be reasonably accomplished in an unreasonable time frame. But if he holds you accountable for failure, you may want to run far and fast from him.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you say this is legit... the quick and dirty way to get this done is to create a series of SQL updates and selects that pull out your exact matches first.

Then from the remaining records, choose a constraint that is "Best" match possible.  Such as Phone number.  You can format all phone numbers to have the same structure.  ie (###) ###-#### or whatever suits your data best.  Then you can do another exact match on those.

Then from the remaining records, choose another constraint.  Such as Address Number.  You'll need to parse the string to find all the numbers in the address.  You can then create a highly probable file of matches.  Although some may have false positives.  Which means you may need to eyeball the data and remove bad matches.

Gathering those bad matches and other remaining records, you can massage your address strings to remove abbreviations.  This can be tedious and is probably not do-able in one day.  Thus you transform "Rd." or "RD" or "Rd" into "Road".  The post office had a list of abbreviations that are most commonly used in addresses.  You can do your best with these replacements and then try an address match again.  This will also be highly inaccurate.

You can then take any leftover records and try one last thing.  You can force an Order to the address parts.  Thus you have street number first, then the street name, then the street type, then any apartment or building designations, then any apartment or building numbers (or letters), etc.  This can improve the accuracy but is still subject to whether the data operators added all the correct info.

As you'll find out, trying to parse and match on addresses can be a very sloppy thing.  In the end, you'll always have non-matches that you'll have to eyeball or just not use.  But once you get to the level where you've replaced and reordered all the info in an address, you can then use other mathematical formulas to find the Levenshtein distance (or something of your own creation).

I hope that helps a little.  Best of luck... and remember... the Kobayashi Maru is a beatable scenario. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I see what your saying.  It's just a lot.  I may use bits and pieces from this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing...

```
Select CLP_Billing_NPI As Billing_NPI
,fullname
,c.FAC_NAME
,c.st_adr
,e.addr1
,e.phyaddr1
,c.phne_num
,e.phone
,PRVDR_NUM
,CRTFCT_TYPE_CD
,Case When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '1' Then  '3 High Cert' 
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '2' Then  '1 Waived'
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '3' Then  '3 High Cert'
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '4' Then  '2 PPMP'
  When CRTFCT_TYPE_CD = '9' Then  '9 REG'
End As LLA_CLIA_Certification_Level
,CRTFCT_EFCTV_DT
,TRMNTN_EXPRTN_DT
Into #tempNC
From [CLIA_LabFindings_NC] lf
LEFT JOIN [provider] P (NOLOCK)
on lf.CLP_Billing_NPI = p.npi
Left join [entity] e (NOLOCK)
on e.entid = p.entityid
INNER JOIN [CLIA_POS] c (NOLOCK)
on (c.[ST_ADR] = e.addr1
or c.[ST_ADR]  = e.[phyaddr1]
or c.[PHNE_NUM]  = e.[Phone])
WHERE [TRMNTN_EXPRTN_DT] > 20150101
order by CLP_Billing_NPI

Begin Tran;
update [LA_Temp].[dbo].[CLIA_LabFindings_NC]
set clia# = NC.clia_num
,[CMS CRTFCT_TYPE_CD] = cast(NC.CRTFCT_TYPE_CD As char(1))
,[LLA CLIA Certification Level:_1Waived_2PPMP_3High Cert] =     NC.LLA_CLIA_Certification_Level
,[CLIA Begin Date] =     Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,NC.CRTFCT_EFCTV_DT,101),101)
,[CLIA End Date] =     Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,NC.TRMNTN_EXPRTN_DT,101),101)
from [LA_Temp].[dbo].[CLIA_LabFindings_NC] lf
inner join #tempNC NC
on CLP_Billing_NPI = NC.Billing_NPI
```

Comment: If there are any comments to improve this, please let me know.